# How to bring TextView & ImageView in front of ImageView using Framelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeList.HomeListAdapter"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_product"
        android:elevation="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ibmplexsanskr_regular"
            android:text="product"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.091"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
            android:text="₩"
            android:textColor="#F57154"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.133"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ibmplexsanskr_regular"
            android:text="dsdsdsds"
            android:textColor="#F57154"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.258"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm making xml of list-adapter item using Framelayout in Android Studio and I want to make it like pic1.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9nM0.png)

But I think it doesn't work. Because I can't bring product name or price in front of product image. And it works like this pic2.

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwWjB.png)

I know that textView(id:price) would be the most recent child on top of the stack but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have set `android:elevation` in your first `ImageView`. You either need to set a higher elevation for your TextViews, or remove the elevation if it's not necessary.